# Laravel MySQL Wrong created_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

Using Laravel & Nova with php 8.1 on Digital Ocean Ubuntu server.
only problem is created_at is 3 hours before correct time.

1. php.ini I have `Asia/Jerusalem` and I checked php -i command to make sure.
2. config/app.php I have `Asia/Jerusalem`
3. mysql select now(); prints correct time.
4. timedatectl prints correct local-time

Comment: Might help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-saving-timestamps-as-utc-but-mysql-server-is-also-adding-an-extra-offset

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with model casting, it was defaulted to datetime but it should be timestamp because the "Z" character at the end of date means it's in ISO8string and should be converted to local time.